# Spring - remove a validation error?

Tags: java, spring

In the context of Spring Webflow 2.0.x......

Is it possible to REMOVE a validation error from within the Spring Errors object during validation? I cant see anything in the API.

i.e.

```
public class MyValidator implements Validator {
    .......
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        MyForm form = (MyForm) target;
        errors.remove(someError); // pseudo code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source, it doesn't seem like this is possible. Neither the `Errors` interface nor any of its implementations provide an API for that.

Comment: Yeah, as I suspected. Surely there must be some way? (rhetorical)

Comment: @Lawrence: I don't think so. There's no way to control the instantiation of the `Errors` object that I know of.